# Finding $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{n(n+1)e^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm really stuck on finding:
$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{n(n+1)e^n}$$

It would be nice if someone could suggest ways to approach this problem.
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion: partial fractions on $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ and the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series),

$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots \quad \big(\,|x|<1\,\big) $$

(Will let you try your hand before giving more details.)

Comment: For using partial fractions, if I split up the denominator into n and n+1 then wouldn't I get a divergent series for 1/n? and I'm not exactly sure how to use Mercator series :S :S :S

Comment: @confusedcat Nope, you get convergent series by the ratio test.

Comment: With the mercator series, I replaced x with 1/e and ended up getting 1-ln(e-1) but I still don't know why I wouldn't get a divergent series for n. Also thank you so much for the very quick response

Comment: @confusedcat Use the ratio test. Or, use the comparison test: the individual terms of your infinite series $\frac{1}{1}e^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2}+\frac{1}{3}e^{-3}+\cdots$ are less than the individual terms of $e^{-1}+e^{-2}+e^{-3}+\cdots$, and you know the latter is convergent, so the partial sums of the former are increasing while bounded above, hence convergent.

Answer (score 5):

$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$. So you want:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n} \frac{z^n}{n} - \frac{1}{z}\sum \frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$

Knowing $$f(z)=-\log(1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n},$$ then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n(n+1)} = f(z)-\frac{1}{z}(f(z)-z) = \left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)f(z) + 1$$

For $z=e^{-1}$, then, you get: $(e-1)\log(1-1/e) + 1.$